# How can I make one <option> tag display in a different colour when the <select> is both open and closed?

Tags: html, css, tags, html-select

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="selectedEventTypeId">
    <option value="1">meeting</option>
    <option value="2" selected="" class="ololool">write contract</option>
</select>
```

And this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ololool {color:green}
</style>
```

However, the option doesn't display in green when the `<select>` is closed:

[image: closed select]

It only does when it's open:

[image: open select]

I want the second `<option>` to be green in both views, open and closed. (But I **don't** want the first option to be displayed in green)

How can I make so?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Edited to hopefully convey the intended question more clearly.

Comment: Apply `class="ololool"` to the first element too.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: he *doesn't* want the first element displayed in green (assuming I've understood the question correctly).

Comment: @user2674303: you're very welcome - you'd got the meaning in there just fine, which is the main thing (and something I couldn't do in your first language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ololool {color:green}
    .blacktext{color:black; }
</style>

<select name="selectedEventTypeId"  onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="blacktext">

                <option value="1" class="blacktext">meeting</option>

                <option value="2" class="ololool">write contract</option>


        </select>
```

Comment: @user2674303: it is not helpful comment! Could use more detail!

Comment: @SidM: To be valid HTML, you want `selected="selected"` (or just `selected`), not `selected="true"`. Try it on [www.validator.w3.org](http://www.validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I want change color for 1 element.ONLY 1. In expand view and in small view

Answer (score -1):

I cant understand very well your question.

But i think that you need to add that class .ololool also to  to make it all with the same style.

```
<select class="ololool">
<option value="2" selected class="ololool" >write contract</option>
</select>
```